# Can an event be possible if its probability is zero?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a computer program that generates any random number between 0 and 1(exclusive). There are infinitely many numbers between 0 and 1. So the probability that the random-number generate the same number twice, will be given by -

$P(E)={1\over \infty}=0$
($\because$ number of favourable outcome = 1, sample space = $\infty$)

But it has happened many times that the program repeats a number, even though, the probability of that event is 0.

Please explain this.

Comment: The whole number-of-favorable-outcomes-devided-by-number-of-elements-of-sample-space approach to probability makes only really sense for finite probability spaces and is even there overly restrictive.

Comment: You do not even need look for repeated numbers -- the probability of generating *any given number* is zero (assuming a true random-number generator and infinite precision). Still it happens every time the generator is run.

Comment: *Consider a computer program that generates any random number between 0 and 1*... Simply put, such a thing does not and cannot exist.

Comment: @Did I don't think you've been into computer programming before. If  you are using Google Chrome press Ctrl+Shift+J and type Math.random() and you'll know what I am talking about. Ctrl+Shift+K if Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: You think wrong and I know what you are talking about. Let me suggest you explain what exactly it is you think the `Math.Random()` thing is proving.

Comment: `Math.random()` does exactly what I meant by `random number generator`.

Comment: @Sandy The point Did is making is that computers are good at following rules and bad at doing things at random. The random numbers generated by computers are not really random, they follow in principle a concrete pattern.

Comment: Sandy: if you drop the idea of using a computer, I think your question is valid. It is possible to (hypothetically) have a RNG which chooses uniformly from $[0,1]$, in which case any given outcome would have probability zero.

Comment: @Xodarap Do you have any specific example in mind, of *a RNG which chooses uniformly from [0,1]*?

Comment: @Sandy *Math.random() does exactly what I meant by random number generator*... Then could you describe as precisely as possible what you mean by `random number generator`? You might want to realize that every RNG for numbers in [0,1] produces numbers taken from a finite subset of [0,1].

Comment: @Michael: I think Did is referring more to the fact that floating point numbers are _not_ arbitrary precision.

Comment: @Willie Good point.

Comment: @Did: What do you mean by "example"? The PDF is easy to write, but if you're asking for a Turing Machine simulation of such an RNG I do not know of one (nor believe one to be possible).

Comment: @Xodarap Usually, the phrase RNG refers to some real-world device. Otherwise, one simply says: random variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the probability of a random variable taking any particular value is $0$, then the sample space must be infinite, and the probability of a repeated value (in a sequence of i.i.d. samples) is also $0$.  So if you see a repeated value, you can conclude with confidence that the probability of that particular value is not zero:

- because the sample space is actually finite, or
- because the samples are not actually independent, or
- because the probability distribution is not actually uniform.

On a computer, *all* of these problems occur at once: there are only finitely many floating-point numbers; pseudo-random number generators do not generate all of these numbers with equal probability; and samples from a pseudo-random number generator are not independent.

Answer (score 10):

A real number representation in computers is not really "real". It is represented by a finite number of bits, so only finitely many values can be represented. That means all random variables generated by a computer will be discrete.

Comment: Nevertheless, assuming infinite memory, all rationals are possible. The effect will be the same, there will be two of the same number following each other. Also 3 times the same.

Comment: Besides, even if a computer were able to generate every real number, it couldn't do it completely randomly. In fact, random algorithms are just [pseudo-random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom).

Comment: And moreover, due to the "birthday" effect, this happens more often than you might expect.

Comment: @sebigu As soon as you restrict yourself to a countable set (rationals), the elements have to have positive probability, and so it's no longer surprising that you can get two of the same in a row.

Comment: @AndreasT: besides that, even if a computer were able to generate completely random numbers, it couldn't generate every real number.

Comment: @Ilya: True. But there in fact ARE computer-components that can produce random numbers, some devices are working with radiation, some, like /dev/random on unix-machines, are working with input entropy. But a computer can (but logically not by itself) create random numbers.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez what is birhtday effect?

Comment: @SandyLee_user53167 I meant an extension of the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). for example, as it states in the Wikipedia article, the probability of getting a number twice from a uniform sample space of $d$ numbers is above half if you choose around $\sqrt{2d\ln 2}$ numbers, so if you get random 32-bit numbers, you should expect to see repetitions after choosing 100,000 numbers or so.

Comment: @sebigu This is more of a philosophical / metaphysical question, because you first have to define what "random" really means, and then you have to determine whether the universe is capable of producing such "random" - this is less relevant here though, because even a decent pseudorandom would have a vanishing probability of repeating itself as the 'sample space' gets larger.

Answer (score 5):

I must be the world’s worst person to be offering an answer to the question posed in the title, and I will be happy to be slapped down by someone who actually knows probability. But it seems to me that if you want to talk probabilities, you need to specify a probability *space*, and you need to specify the probability *measure* on it. Until you do both these things, you are merely talking philosophy, not mathematics.

Consider the example of a unit square $S$ as probability space, and ordinary Lebesgue measure on it, so that the probability of a point being in a subset $A\subset S$ is the area of $A$. Now draw the line from one corner to the opposite corner, and consider this subset $D\subset S$. What is the probability of a point lying on the diagonal $D$? Zero, of course, since a line has zero area. But there *are* points on the diagonal.

Now, to amplify @Tunococ’s good answer, let me say that one *must* make a careful distinction between *real numbers* and *computer numbers*. There are only a finite number of (floating point) computer numbers in your favorite computer, but uncountably infinitely many real numbers. I once sat in a room where the speaker (correctly) stated that it’s impossible to determine on a computer whether two real numbers are equal, and a Respected Member of the computer science department of my university said “Of course it’s possible: take their difference and see if it’s zero.” But he was wrong. For instance, there’s no way to tell by comparing the numbers on your computer that $\arctan(1/3)+\arctan(1/2)=\pi/4$, even though Pure Thought shows that it’s true.

Comment: The probability that you are the world's worst person to offer an answer to this question is extremely low.

Answer (score 3):

An event having probability zero does not mean it is impossible, but that is unlikely to happen. If you look at the qoutients of all pairs of your numbers, and take the quotient of those which are equal by all pairs, for infitite many pairs this quotient will be zero. This means that there are pairs of equal numbers, but there are relatively few.

Another example: Take a pipe. The probability of the pipe breaking at a point is zero, but the probability for breaking might be not zero. If it breakes, it breakes at a certain point. the probability for this was zero, but it happend.

So, finally, probability zero does only mean relatively unlikely, not impossible.

Comment: Even if you know, that a pipe breaks, but you don't have a knowledge where it did break, the probability it have been broken at a particular point is zero.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of factors that bound an infinite sample space of a computer program to a finite space:

1. A number in a computer program has a limited fixed representation. This is limited by the hardware.
2. Widely used random number generators (such as [`Random class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) in C#) produce only [pseudo-random sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). There are [real random number generators](http://www.random.org/), but they produce numbers from finite space.

These limitations transforms the equation:

$P(E)={1\over \infty}=0$

To

$P(E)={1\over N}=0$

Where *N* is a very large positive finite number.

This makes *P(E)* a very small positive number.

---

However, if we consider a hypothetical computer in an ideal environment with infinite amount of memory and processing power to compute real random numbers from infinite space. Then, indeed

$P(E)={1\over \infty}=0$

will hold true and you will never see two identical numbers.